# How do I tell SBT-proguard to mark scala-library as "provided"?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-proguard

Is there any way to treat the "scala-library" JAR as provided using SBT 0.13.7?

I'm using sbt-proguard to package my JAR, which is later loaded dynamically into an application that already has an appropriately versioned scala-library on the classpath.

Comment: I'm able to use sbt-assembly and [exclude the scala-library](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#excluding-scala-library-jars), but I'd like to use the other functionality that proguard provides at some point.

Answer (score 0):

The sbt-proguard plugin defaults to swallowing the entire world. If you don't want to process everything with proguard (and include it in the resulting jar), then you will need to redefine the inputs. For example with something like this in your build.sbt:

`ProguardKeys.inputs in Proguard <<= exportedProducts in Compile map { _.files }`